# How to use arrays as __set __get hidden variable?

Tags: php, magic-methods

I have class session

```
class Session {
    public $storage;
    private function __construct($storage) {
        $this->storage = $storage ? $storage : new stdClass();
    }
    function __get($name) {
        return $this->storage->$name;
    }
    function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->storage->$name = $value;
    }
    function __isset($name) {
        return isset($this->storage->$name);
    }
}
```

And I want to to have array as key:

```
    $id = uniqid('res_');
    if (!isset($session->mysql)) {
        $session->mysql = array();
    }
    $session->mysql[$id] = array(
        'host' => $host,
        'user' => $username,
        'pass' => $password,
        'name' => $db);
```

but got error: `Indirect modification of overloaded property Session::$mysql has no effect`
I've try to store it in variable using referece:

```
$mysql = &$session->mysql[$id]
```

but go the same error, if I don't use `&` I don't have the error but the data is not save.

How can I make this working? I would like to have tree like access to store variables.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, I need to use

```
function &__get($name) {
}
```

and it work.